# Api Delete Angular 5

Tags: html, angular

Hello i'm working in Angular 5 and my api delete works (postman & site --> link = api/employees/:id --> localhost:4200/api/employees/5a2025db26589c230865527a) , but I think my HTML code is wrong or the steps in between. Can somebody help me plz i've been stuck at this all day..

HTML :

```
<h2>Info employees</h2>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Wage</th>
    </tr>

    <tr  *ngFor="let employee of employees">
      <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ employee.age }}</td>
      <td> {{ employee.email }} </td>
      <td> {{ employee.wage}}</td>
      <td>{{employee._id}}</td>
      <td>

      <a href=""  class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="deleteEmployee(employee._id)">Delete</a>



      </td>
      </tr>


  </table>
```

Component.ts :

```
deleteEmployee(id){
        var employees = this.employees;

        this._dataService.deleteEmployee(id)
    .subscribe(data => {
            if(data.n == 1){
                for(var i = 0;i < employees.length;i++){
                    if(employees[i]._id == id){
                        employees.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

data.service :

```
deleteEmployee(id){
        return this._http.delete('/api/employees/'+id)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Comment: what is `if(data.n == 1)`  for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `data-ng-click` with `(click)` and make the HTML element a `<button>` since it's not redirecting anywhere.

Edit: `employees.splice(i, 1);` replace with `this.employees.splice(i, 1);` to reflect the change in the view.

Actually, you need to change the logic of

```
if(data.n == 1){
                for(var i = 0;i < employees.length;i++){
                    if(employees[i]._id == id){
                        employees.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Because basically you are deleting user in the view without considering the data of the backend service. What response do you get from that `DELETE` endpoint ? Does it return the deleted user or the `id` of the deleted user ?

Comment: <button  class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteEmployee(employee._id)">Delete</button>

Comment: I edited my answer with more info but yes `<button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteEmployee(employee._id)">Delete</button>` looks good now - still there are some issues left

Comment: even in the backend

Comment: still it's wrong, cause u don't check that the server sends back. what if the user is not deleted from the database and you deleted it from the view ? cause it will happen with that logic. for example change the endpoint to cause an error before deleting the user -> in the view u still delete it. hope that this helped

Comment: response --> Employee 5a2025db26589c230865527a deleted!

Comment: the employee is deleted in my database

Comment: great :) what i am trying to say is that if you comment all the code in the delete endpoint (server), then go to angular and click the delete button for a user then that user will be deleted from the list and if you refresh the page you will see that user again. am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe little late ..but that if you try something like this .. with `.filter()` ES6 (also Typescript) Array native method ..

so like:

```
eleteEmployee(id){
        var employees = this.employees; //why use it?? ..no need it

        this._dataService.deleteEmployee(id)
    .subscribe(data => {
            if(data.n == 1){
                this.employees = this.employees.filter(xx=> xx._id != id)  // <--- so filter and RETURN ALL non matching given ID
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope it helps you !! ...